# Listview crashes when scrolling only on kitkat

Tags: android, listview, android-4.4-kitkat

but it crashes only on kitkat devices and also it works on kitkat emulator , so i don't get anything in logcat.
if i remove `imageView.setImageResource(imageId.get(position))` app works on kitkat devices too but i need that.

here is my code:

CustomList:

```
public class CustomList extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final Activity      context;
    private final List<String>  names;
    private final List<Integer> imageId;
    private Typeface            myFont;


    public CustomList(Activity context, List<String> names, List<Integer> imageId) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_single, names);
        this.context = context;
        this.names = names;
        this.imageId = imageId;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_single, null, true);
        TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
        SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences("settings", 0);
        String font_name = sp.getString("font", "yeken.ttf");
        float text_size = sp.getFloat("size", 18);
        if (font_name.equals("yeken.ttf")) {
            myFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), font_name);

        }
        else
            myFont = android.graphics.Typeface.DEFAULT;

        txtTitle.setText(names.get(position));

        if (myFont != null)
            txtTitle.setTypeface(myFont);

        txtTitle.setTextSize(text_size);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId.get(position));
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

list_single.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow android:gravity="right" android:background="@drawable/list_item_bg2">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="test" android:gravity="center"/>
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img"
                android:layout_width="70dip"
                android:layout_height="70dip"
                android:src="@drawable/gray_button" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_marginRight="10dip"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:layout_margin="2dip"
        android:background="@drawable/list_devider" />
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: stacktrace? perhaps you didn't put all necessary resources in your drawables folder. Try providing resources for hdpi, xhdpi, etc.

Comment: Which KitKat device you are using to run the application ?

Comment: i put all drawables in hdpi folder @einschnaehkeee

Comment: Xperia z1 and Samsung s5 @naranz

Comment: then you should also put drawables in xhdpi and xxhdpi, because those phones are one of those.

Comment: First, you should post the full stackTrace of your error using logcat. Second, make sure that all your list_single.xml files contains an ImageView with the `img` id. Third, you should **not** get SharedPreferences nor create a TypeFace inside this `getView()` method. Take a look at the ViewHolder pattern for listView implementations.

Comment: i used ViewHolder but i still have this problem